# How can I use my stand-alone ASP.NET Core navigation- microservice in my ASP.NET MVC monolith?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, microservices

I work with huge monolith project.

I am looking for ways to start, slowly, transitioning to other technologies. Currently I am looking for how to do this with ASP.NET Core, but will (in the future) experiment with other techs, such as React etc...

Someone mentioned keyword 'mosaic' at some point, but I was unable to find reading relevant material searching this/

For the sake of simplicity - let's 'use' asp.net core as an example

"I have a stand-alone ASP.NET Core microservice, that provides me a navigation bar. I want to use this in my current, monolithic ASP.NET MVC software. How?"

.NET Framework (of ASP.NET MVC) : 4.6.1

Comment: if the projects reference each other you will need to use .net standard

Comment: The goal would be to have something similar to iFrame in a sense that I load an completely external component (the navigation microservice) into the section I need it (navigation area).